# generic viewmodel control (MVC)

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controls, generics

I am trying to create a generic user control.
So I need a user control with a generic parameter.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IPager<T>>" %>
```

The control doesn't really care what the T is. It works with any T.

When I render the control, I can instantiate it with the generic argument.

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial<MyClass>("Pager", Model); %>
```

That's the basic idea - is there any way to make a user control that takes an extra generic argument. If I wanted to build such a thing, where would I start?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use `IPager<object>` in the `<%@Control %>` declaration. Then, the covariant generics support means that you can pass it an `IPager<MyClass>` as a model in `RenderPartial` and it will still work just fine.

Comment: You are correct, I tried this approach in studio 2008 but it doesn't work. You need covariant types. I will try and motivate to use the new framework. Pity it doesn't work with 2008. It should have.